# jQuery : How to return an element by the value of a class of its child

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a block of buttons  , and i wanna return the name of the parent "li"  which is containing the button (a) with the class "is active"

```
<li class="page" name="1"><a href="#" class="is-active">1</a></li> 
<li class="page" name="2"><a href="#">2</a></li>
<li class="page" name="3"><a href="#">3</a></li>
<li class="page" name="4"><a href="#">4</a></li>
<li class="page" name="5"><a href="#">5</a></li>
```

i want to return in this case the first element  with name "1".

i have tried 
**attr("class", "is-active")**
and
the method **find().class("is-active")**

but that didn't work

any suggestions ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:has()` filter will do it

```js
console.log(

 $('.page:has(.is-active)').attr('name')

)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="page" name="1"><a href="#" class="is-active">1</a></li> 
<li class="page" name="2"><a href="#">2</a></li>
<li class="page" name="3"><a href="#">3</a></li>
<li class="page" name="4"><a href="#">4</a></li>
<li class="page" name="5"><a href="#">5</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the parent using the [parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) method:

`$('.is-active').parent().attr('name');`

In your example for the `class()` you were missing the period prefix.

Comment: But I'm not sure if the attribute "name" is valid,  for 'li' elements.  Can use: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes